# Cast in consteval function fails; works outside

Tags: c++, consteval

I'm trying to write a thin wrapper layer to interface c++ classes from python.

Python itself uses those three signatures to call a c function from py:

```
typedef PyObject *(*PyCFunction)(PyObject *, PyObject *);
typedef PyObject *(*PyCFunctionWithKeywords)(PyObject *, PyObject *, PyObject *);
typedef PyObject *(*PyNoArgsFunction)(PyObject *);
```

Unfortunately, the `PyMethodDef` struct stores a function as `PyCFunction` and a `flags` member to decide at runtime which function is actually stored/called.

I wrote a function template which takes three `PyObject*`s and returns one `PyObject*`, essentially a `PyCFunctionWithKeywords`, calling the classes member function with either zero, one or two arguments (as the first argument is the instance itself).

```
template<auto Fn>
PyObject* member_wrapper(PyObject* obj, PyObject* args, PyObject* kwargs)
```

`Fn` is the member function pointer to wrap. Given a macro:

```
#define PY_WRAP(fn) (PyCFunction)::py::member_wrapper<fn>
```

I can successfully set the function pointer:

```
PyCFunction func = PY_WRAP(&MyClass::SomeFunc);
```

Above compiles as expected. However I've tried using a consteval function instead of a macro:

```
template<typename T>
consteval PyCFunction make_wrapper(T fn) {
    return (PyCFunction)::py::member_wrapper<fn>;
}

PyCFunction func = make_wrapper(&MyClass::SomeFunc);
```

This however fails with:

```
 error C2440: Cannot convert "PyObject *(__cdecl *)(PyObject *,PyObject *,PyObject *)" to "PyCFunction"
```

I'm confused why the cast works in the macro but fails in the consteval function.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is not allowed at compile-time. This includes those C-style casts that use it under the hood.

Comment: Thats unfortunate. So I'm stuck with macros?

Comment: Just use a non-constexpr function? And let your compiler optimize it.

Comment: I can't pass the function `fn` as template argument to `member_wrapper` in this case, however. And since I need to have a c-style function pointer in the end, I can't store the member function pointer as state anywhere. Or atleast I can't think of a way. Of course, using `::py::member_wrapper<&MyClass::SomeFunc>;` directly works aswell but then again requires a cast, and the goal is to make it as easy to use as possible, i.e. just a single "function" (or macro) call, passing the member function pointer.

Comment: Now that I actually looked at the code, you won't be able to use a function parameter as a template argument, `consteval` or not. Function parameters are never considered to be `constexpr` inside of a function. The call syntax has to be `make_wrapper<...>()` or `make_wrapper<...>` (template variable).

Answer (score 2):

`consteval` is not a macro; it's not just a textual copy-and-paste. It's a way of decorating a function such that using it outside of constant expression evaluation is a compile error. `consteval` functions therefore must follow the rules of `constexpr` functions.

Among those rules are that `reinterpret_cast`, and any C-style cast that would be equivalent to one, is expressly forbidden. Conversion of a function pointer to one signature to a different signature requires a `reinterpret_cast`, even if you're using a C-style cast. So it's not allowed.

You can use a non-`constexpr` function call if you want to avoid a macro. But you can't use a compile-time construct for something that cannot be done at compile-time.